# Kubernetes rolling update for same image

Tags: kubernetes

Document of kubernetes says to do rolling update for a updated docker image. In my case I need to do rolling update for my pods using the same image. Is it possible to do rolling update of a replication controller for a same docker image?

Comment: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408593/how-to-use-rolling-update-to-re-pull-container-image

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you cannot. If you try to (e.g., using the method George describes), you get the following error:

```
error:  must specify a matching key with non-equal value in Selector for api
see 'kubectl rolling-update -h' for help.
```

The above with kubernetes v1.1.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, Try this command:

```
$ kubectl rolling-update <rc name> --image=<image-name>:<tag>
```

If your image:tag has been used before, you may like to do following to make sure you get the latest image on kubernetes.

```
$ docker pull <image-name>:<tag>
```